# Three person simultaneous random walk

Tags: random-walk, random-functions

So let's say you have 3 people walking 100m, from one wall to another.

Each move each person independently draws 3 integers, each between -10 and 5 with equal probability. You, as the coordinator, get to choose whether or not all three people accept that move. If you accept, they each walk their respective number of steps forward or backwards.

What is the optimal strategy to get all three people to the opposite wall in the minimum number of draws?

Comment: What about two persons? Is there a known solution?

Comment: Is a person "safe" (i.e out of the game) once he reaches the wall at 100m? I assume a person's backward movement is limited by the wall at the starting position.

Comment: BTW, I also assume you mean that each person draws a single integer, not 3 integers.

Comment: yes, there are three integers per draw, one for each person. To my knowledge there is no known solution for two people. Also, people are not "safe" once reaching the wall. The intuitive answer, which is to just accept any move where the sum of the 3 integers is zero, seems like it may be less effective because of this, as getting one person who is already close to the other wall is not very valuable if the others are far behind, because that person will inevitably be moved back in future draws.

Comment: Another question is how exactly the "minimum number of draws" is defined. Through expectation? Anyway, I would suggest solving the two-people case, if there is no known solution. It is also very interesting, must be easier to solve and could provide some insights for the three-people case.

Comment: Yes, through expectation. The actual idea behind this problem came from an online game that my friend was playing, in which you have three stats that can increase or decrease with each draw, capping at 100. We wanted to make a bot that will automatically generate the correct move and click agree or disagree whenever resources are available to make a draw. I agree that the two person case may be more straight forward to solve.

Comment: If anyone has an educated guess as a to a strategy that you think may work best, feel free to post without a proof. I have Matlab code in place to verify if it will result in the lowest expected number of draws, and I can compare it to the sum > 0  approach.